# Dynamically creating a component from another component

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am trying to create a cart that loads the items dynamically.

**Sidebar Component .TS**

```
@ViewChild('cartContainer', { read: ViewContainerRef }) public container;
public componentRef: ComponentRef<any>;

public createComponent(type: any) {
  this.container.clear();
  const factory: ComponentFactory<any> = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(CartComponent);
  this.componentRef = this.container.createComponent(factory);
  this.componentRef.instance.type = type;
  this.componentRef.instance.output.subscribe(event => console.log(event));
}
```

**Sidebar Component .HTML**

```
<ng-template #cartContainer></ng-template>
```

**Cart Component .TS**

```
export class CartComponent {
  @Input() public type = 'success';
  @Output() output = new EventEmitter();
}
```

**Cart Component .HTML**

```
<div id="cd-cart" class="speed-in">
<h1 (click)="output.next('output')">Cart {{ type | json}}</h1>
<ul class="cd-cart-items" style="height: 50vh!important;">
<li *ngFor="let CartItem of CartItems; let index = i;">
  <span class="cd-qty">1x</span> CRISTOMORADO MAIZMORADO KG
  <div class="cd-price">S/.7.00</div>
  <a href="#0" class="cd-item-remove cd-img-replace">Remove</a>
</li>
```

**StoreItems Component .TS**

```
constructor(private _sidebarComponent: SidebarComponent){}

private addItem(key: string, value: object) {
  this._sidebarComponent.createComponent(value);
}
```

**StoreItems Component .HTML**

```
<div class="ui-g">
<div *ngFor="let Item of Items" class="ui-g-2">
<a href="javascript:;" (click)="addItem('cart', Items)"><md-card class="item-card">
  <div class="ui-g-2-top">{{ Item.Item_Description }}</div>
  <div class="ui-g-2-bottom">{{ MONEY_CHAR }}{{ Item.ITEM_Sale_Price | number : '1.2-2'}}</div>
</md-card></a>
</div>
```

**LayoutComponent .HTML**

```
<app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
```

However, when I call addItem() and it calls createComponent(), it doesn't recognize my ViewChild()

```
Cannot read property 'clear' of undefined
```

What am I missing?

Comment: when and where do you call `addItem` ?

Comment: Please see my edits

Comment: why do you use `ng-template`? can you try with `ng-container`?

Comment: sure, i can try. but the problem is that the ViewChild from SidebarComponent is not being recognized after injecting it into StoreItems. It works, otherwise.

Comment: how is `SidebarComponent` created and injected? can you maybe create a plunker? it's hard to understand your setup

Comment: check the constructor in storeitems.component.ts in my post

Comment: it doesn't tell me much, you simply injected the parent component class instance. I'm curious how `SidebarComponent ` is created

Comment: create a plunker, it's hard to understand all the details

Comment: in which part of your html are you using your SidebarComponent selector? Like, `<sidebar></sidebar>`?

Comment: currently trying to make a plunkr, also added where sidebar is <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>

Answer (score 1):

I have tried something like this and it's working fine for me

```
import { Directive, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[my-host]',
})
export class MyHostDirective {
  constructor(public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) {
  }
}

import { Component, ViewChild, ComponentFactoryResolver } from '@angular/core';
export class YourComponent{
 @ViewChild(MyHostDirective) myHost: MyHostDirective;
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.renderDynamicComponents();
  }


  renderDynamicComponents() {
    let component = this.widgetsStoreFactory.getWidgetComponent("ComponentName");
    let componentFactory = this._componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(component);
    let viewContainerRef = this.myHost.viewContainerRef;
    viewContainerRef.clear();
    let componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
    (<IModel>componentRef.instance).YourProperty = "DataToPass";


  }
}


<ng-template my-host>


</ng-template>
```

Finally please add the dynamic components to the entryComponents of your module

https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

https://fromjami.com/2017/06/26/load-components-dynamically-at-runtime-in-angular-4/